# Not able to access AWS EC2 instance when connected to VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have set up an AWS EC2 server, and installed cassandra on it. I am successfully able to connect to cassandra and use it through my local machine using the public IP of my ec2 instance.

Now, I need to be connected to a VPN to continue with my work. But, after connecting to the VPN, I am not able to ssh into the ec2 server or access the installed cassandra.

My security group allows all traffic (IPv4 and IPv6).
I'm new to this, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: does the network you're connecting to through VPN allows outgoing connections on TCP port 22 (ssh) ?

Comment: What type of VPN connection is it? Something to your workplace, or to AWS? Can you SSH to anything else on the Internet via the VPN connection? It is quite common for workplace networks to restrict SSH access from their network. More details, please.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have installed proton vpn and as the VPN starts, my ec2 instance becomes inaccesible (both SSH and xRDP). The only resort is to reboot but that stops the VPN running in shell.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I have the same issue, using OpenVPN